# A Game You Know

Tags: rebus

[image: From left to right: {A stylized eye looking at the viewer; The capital letter J (no serifs); A circle containing a question mark, with 9 lines of various lengths pointing in multiple directions; The capital letter Z (no serifs)}. All symbols are black on white background. The Image has a thin black border.]

What game am I thinking of?
Answers should contain the game's name and an explanation.
I believe this is a medium difficulty rebus, let's see how fast you guys can solve it :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can only think of one game everybody would know that ends in a "z" or "zee", and the other hints don't fit "yahtzee".

However, if I add another layer of deduction to the rebus, I end up with an extremely well known game, namely:

> Tetris.

Assuming that the third symbol means that you have no idea which direction you should go, then the solution to the rebus is

> "I J LOST Z",

which looks a bit weird until you realise it's the

> names of all the [Tetris pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino#One-sided_tetrominoes) written one after another in alphabetical order.

Comment: I also came up with this game since there are J and Z (I played this a lot so J and Z do ring the bells) but didn't know how to get that especially from the symbol. Great job!

Comment: @athin, yeah, I also had the solution first, and then had to work back from there to figure out a suitable meaning for the symbol. :-)

Comment: @Bass yes, that's it. Is a second layer not common in rebuses?

Comment: IIRC, originally the idea of a rebus was to write names in a way that could be read by the illiterate, and most of the rebus puzzles I’ve seen (or created) follow among the same lines. Since your puzzle contained other elements than just the picture, I’d say this was a skillfully crafted and very welcome variation on the usual theme. You can click on the tag [tag:rebus], should you want to do statistical analysis on PSE’s 350-odd rebus puzzles to decide what is actually common and what isn’t :-)

Answer (score 2):

More of a guess than a complete answer,
Is it something related to:

> Maze or Jumanji (The board game)

Explanation:

The eye:

> You have to pay attention to where you are going in a maze and in Jumanji

Letter J:

> Fits more in the word 'Jumanji'

Question mark with arrows

> Represents the doubt of chosing a path to follow

The Letter Z

> Fits more in the word 'Maze'

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I will add a first hint tomorrow, if nobody else gets the correct answer by then.

Answer (score 2):

Or it could also be:

> The old, classic game [JezzBall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JezzBall)

The eye:

> You had to keep your eye on the balls as they moved across your screen.

The J:

> The "J" in "JezzBall"

The symbol:

> The balls went in multiple directions, all over your screen.

The Z:

> There are two "Z"s in "JezzBall"

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably wrong, but is it:

> ouija board?

The eye:

> The board is supposed to see what you do.

The J:

> The name has a J in it.

The symbol:

> It moves in all directions.

The Z:

> It goes to all letters of the alphabet in the game, including z.